# Is it Windows or the battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, power-management

my laptop has an 8 year old battery. my battery didn't charge and i froze it after freezing it, my battery charged again and lasted for 3 hour of normal use and like 2.5 hour of video and sound use. But, when I execute a command in CMD. and the command is like this:

```
powercfg /BATTERYREPORT
powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY
```

then I checked its cycle but, when I checked it, it shows that there's "0" cycle and when I charge, my full charge capacity was like up and down! right now in most of the times, my battery charges at only 92% and charges rarely at 100% when in use! i'm so surprised! here are all the HTML (provided by the command) about my battery...

for battery report, here:

[Battery report(on google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11tgr2Mv1gVLKVCSHeKj8eOy3sBJ4GHB3/view?usp=sharing)

for the sleep study, here:

[Sleep study(on google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1afMApI5T_dxzSxZjskbOYyn8AFeayubo/view?usp=sharing)

please shed me some light about my battery... thanks! oh and right now my battery is stuck at 92% like so;

[Battery Pic which is stuck on 92%(imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAhG.jpg)

i'm so grateful and thankful for the person who have shed some light for me! TY in advance! 
oh and when i install BatteryBar, it showed unknown?!

UPDATE:

Battery Bar showed the correct Battery Percentage! But,
here's the data reported:

```
Percent:        92.3%
Capacity:       26,246 mWh of 28,435 mWh
Charge Rate:    0 mW
Time Remaining: Unknown @ 11:55 am (Charging)
Elapsed Time:   0:08 (since 92.3%)
Full Runtime:   Calculating
Battery Wear:   45.0% of 51,700 mWh
```

Oh and my battery tech is Li-Ion my charger says my battery is full and my lappy says it's not? I have an indicator here which is red... (●'◡'●)

UPDATE: now windows reported 96% after unplugging the charger at 92%

Comment: Your battery is finished. Its 8 years old, and lithium batteries wear out over time.  I can't read your battery reports from my cellphone but I expect you additionally have a dead cell, which is drawing power faster then your charger can top it up while your computer is in use.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! I expect more! 

Comment: Here's one more: your battery is very likely finished. (: It'll very likely never reach 100% again because when one or more cells in the battery die, it'll never be able to reach 100% of spec capacity. Most batteries do not have electronics intelligent enough to detect this. This will cause all sorts of funny readings in chargers and capacity indicators and these will never be accurate with dead cells.

Comment: I'll add one as well. The battery is finished, get a new one.

Comment: In addition, the typical battery lifespan is about 3 years.